# Best database practices for a global single element?

Tags: mysql, django, database

I've been recently developing a Django app (using MySQL) that globally depends on a single constantly-changing list of values. I save them on a JSON Field that's something like

```
{'value1':0.123, 'value2':2.33214, ...}
```

I use a cron job that runs 24/7 that retrieves this object once at the start and then updates it every second. To do this, i do something like

```
L = ValuesList.objects.all().first()
if L is None:
    L = ValuesList.objects.create(my_json=some_default)
```

And this code is pretty much present whenever i want to get the values. If that looks bad, i even used to do

```
try:
    L = ValuesList.objects.get(id=1)
catch:
    L = ValuesList.objects.create(my_json=some_default)
```

My question comes from that situation, it looks messy because i know beforehand that it's a SINGLE object, so i figured there could be something more appropriate to use for THE object (which, by the way, is guaranteed to exist, the whole business logic depends on this), instead of doing a model, creating tables and then searching for the first element if it exists.

Is there a better way that i do not know of to store and retrieve a single object? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well since you guarantee that there is only *one* element, you can perform a `.get(..)` **without** any filtering.

In case the object does not exists, we want to perform a `create`. We can combine the two with a [**`get_or_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create):

```
L, created = ValuesList.objects.get_or_create(
    defaults={
        'my_json': some_default
    })
```

Depending on the database system you use, this can be performed with a *single* query. It will try to fetch the single object (we do not need to filter, since it is guaranteed that there is only one). In case it does not exists, Django will *create* an instance, with the values in the `defaults` dictionary as initial values.

The function returns a 2-tuple with as first element the object (fetched or constructed, here `L`), and as second item a boolean that indicates whether an object was constructed (here `created`).

You can encapsulate this logic in the model class (for example a `@classmethod`) that allows us to fetch the single instance.